# How to translate these hex numbers into bitwise values?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm looking through the source code of a project written in C. Here is a list of options that are defined (no these aren't the real defines...not very descriptive!)

```
...
#define OPTION_5    32768
#define OPTION_6    65536
#define OPTION_7    0x20000L
#define OPTION_8    0x40000L
#define OPTION_9    0x80000L
```

I'd like to add a new option `OPTION_10` but before I do that, I'd like to understand what exactly the hex numbers represent?

Do these numbers convert to the expected decimal values of 131,072 262,144 524,288 ? If so, why not keep the same format as the earlier options?

Comment: th hex representation is much more reliable.

Comment: They probably knew the first two by heart (2^15, 2^16) but no further... so they switched methods - don't know why they wouldn't have switched the first set too, though - perhaps they abhor consistency?

Comment: @johnny: Even though I know the first couple powers of two by heart also, I would still use the hex values because of the easy-to-remember pattern: 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x100, 0x200, 0x400, 0x800, 0x1000, etc. At least it'll be immediately obvious to readers that there is a rhyme and reason to their values.

Comment: @In_silico: yeah, I was just providing some possible rationale for _their_ using the decimal equivalents, though I totally agree with you - makes them much less prone to error and much easier to read... (and is more consistent, as previously mentioned)

Comment: what happened to the answer with the table? I kinda liked that one, just wanted them to prefix binary somehow (though I realize binary support / prefixing is compiler-dependent, so perhaps a note would be in order...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do these numbers convert to the expected decimal values of 131,072

Yes. You can use Google for the conversion: search for "[0x20000 in decimal](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x20000%20in%20decimal)".

> If so, why not keep the same format as the earlier options?

I guess simply because programmers know their powers of two up to 65536 and prefer hexadecimal, where they are more recognizable, above that.

The `L` suffix forces the literal constant to be typed at least as a `long int`, **but the chosen type may be still larger if that's necessary to hold the constant**. It's probably unnecessary in your program and the programmer used it because s/he didn't understand the emphasized clause. The nitty-gritty details are in 6.4.4.1, page 56 of the C99 standard.

Comment: search links: [0x20000 in decimal](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x20000+in+decimal) or [binary](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x20000+in+binary)

Comment: I guess I was thrown off by the ending 'L' of the number

Comment: @DTest L specifies a long instead of the default constant type of int. Otherwise, it has no effect on the value.

Answer (score 2):

Just a further thought to add to the existing answers, I prefer to define such flags more like this:

```
enum {
    OPTION_5_SHIFT = 15,
    OPTION_6_SHIFT,
    OPTION_7_SHIFT,
    OPTION_8_SHIFT,
    OPTION_9_SHIFT,
    OPTION_10_SHIFT
};

enum {
    OPTION_5 = 1L << OPTION_5_SHIFT,
    OPTION_6 = 1L << OPTION_6_SHIFT,
    OPTION_7 = 1L << OPTION_7_SHIFT,
    OPTION_8 = 1L << OPTION_8_SHIFT,
    OPTION_9 = 1L << OPTION_9_SHIFT,
    OPTION_10 = 1L << OPTION_10_SHIFT
};
```

This avoids having explicitly calculated constants and makes it much easier to insert/delete values, etc.

Comment: +1 for the enumeration constant automatically increasing - didn't know about that... Easier insert/delete of values (at least in the enum part) may not be desirable in this case, but you can still get rid of (e.g.) `OPTION_7` and everything's fine...

Comment: @johnny: yes, and if you can have gaps in the enum values if you need them, e.g. to maintain values after a deletion, by adding explicit values as needed.

Answer (score 0):

They represent the same kind of numbers, they are all powers of two. Or, too see it in a different light, they are all binary numbers with exactly one one (no phun intended).

One possible reason why they are written the they way they are (even though the reason isn't a good one) is that many programmers know the following sequence by hart:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
```

This sequence corresponds to the first 17 powers of two. Then things are not that easy any more, so they probably switched to hex (being too lazy to change all the earlier numbers).

Answer (score 0):

The specific values represent bit flag options, which can be combined with the bitwise OR operator `|`:

```
flags = (OPTION_5|OPTION_6);
```

You will see from the binary representation of these values, that each has one unique bit set, to allow combining them using bitwise OR:

```
0x8000L   = 32768   = 00000000 00000000  10000000 00000000
0x10000L  = 65536   = 00000000 00000001  00000000 00000000
0x20000L  = 131072  = 00000000 00000010  00000000 00000000
0x40000L  = 262144  = 00000000 00000100  00000000 00000000
0x80000L  = 524288  = 00000000 00001000  00000000 00000000
0x100000L = 1048576 = 00000000 00010000  00000000 00000000
```

To find out if a flag has been set in the flags variable, you can use the bitwise AND operator `&`:

```
if(flags & OPTION_6)
{
    /* OPTION_6 is active */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Each digit of a number represents a multiplication factor of the number's numerical system's base to the power of the digit's position in the number, counted from right to left, beginning with zero.

So 32768 = 8 * 10^0 + 6 * 10^1 + 7 * 10^2 + 2 * 10^3 + 3 * 10^4.

(Hint for the sake of completeness: x^0 = 1, x^1 = x.)

Hexadecimal numbers have 16 digits (0 - 9, A (~10) - F (~15)) and hence a base of 16, so 0x20 = 0 * 16^0 + 2 * 16^1.

Binary numbers have 2 digits and a base of 2, so 100b = 1 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0.

Knowing that you should be able to figure the rest yourself and handle binary and hexadecimal numbers, understand that each number you listed is twice its predecessor, what decimal values the hex numbers have, what the next decimal number in the row should be, and how to express OPTION_10 in any numerical system, and particularly binary, decimal and hexadecimal.

Comment: Discussion [moved to chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3303/discussion-between-johnny-and-karx11erx)